# Add a template content to detail tab

Tags: layout, xml

I want to add some content within the product detail tab.
[image]

I created my template below

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="additional_product_details" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/additional_product_details.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
```

I tried to use the `<move />` syntax to achieve this but was unsuccessful.

Please note: I am not trying to create a custom tab.

Comment: How did you finally solve it? I'm facing the same problem and decorating the `description` value in `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml` with additional content from another attribute just doesn't seem right to me.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can add a new tab.

In your `view/frontend/layout` folder, create a xml file named `catalog_product_view.xml` and add the following content. Do note the values to change. If you are adding this from a theme, then you will not have a `view/frontend/layout` folder. Instead you will have to create either `Magento_Catalog/layout` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

      <body>

        <!--Product Main Content-->
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <!--Detail tab section-->
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Details" name="product.info.details" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media">

                <!--our custom tab -->
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.uniqueNameForTab" as="customTab" template="Magento_Catalog::path/to/custom-features-template-file.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
                        <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">20</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>

            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

If you are still facing problems, I have a working code which I added multiple tabs. Let me know.

Comment: Hello John. As I mention in my post I am not trying to add a custom tab. I am trying to add content into the details tab directly. The code you provided is to create a custom tab which is not what I am looking for. For example what I am trying to do here is add a title in the detail tab "CHECK OUT THE PRODUCT INFORMATION" and some links. This will reside in the box as the picture shows 

If that is not possible, I was thinking I could maybe create a custom tab, add my content, but what I could not figure out was how to grab the product description information to also add to my custom tab.

Comment: I can see that you have edited your question. Previously it mentioned about adding a tab. You can try adding a `after plugin` to "get product description attribute" and inject your content directly into the description field data.

Comment: John I had to edit it, because I dont know how you read my question and interpreted I was asking to add a tab. You probably only read the last past and mistook what I said. I know how to add a custom tab, look at the image I provided it has 3 custom tabs already.